# AChartEngine does not display the maximum chart value - Bar Chart

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I am working on Achart Engine and i am facing 2 issues

Issue 
1) i am facing exactly same problem as posted in the screen shot here [displaying max chart values on Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048709/achartengine-does-not-display-the-maximum-chart-value)

2) suppose in the 3 bars if i one among the bar is 0 say middle one then the bar will not be drawn and shows blank between the two bars, but i dont want to show some space.

On Issues what i want to acheive:

Issue 1) My Ymax value is 50 ,i can make the Y max value to 60 so that the max value is displayed and will not cut.But what happens is now its display 10,20,30,40,50 in Y axis but if i make it 60 it displays 20,40,60 but i want it to display 10,20,30,40,50,60.

Issue 2) If the middle bar value is 0 or any other bar value which is draw is 0 then i dont want to show a space there or dont draw the bar at all.

Please help me to acheive this.

EDIT:

SCREEN SHOT :

I cannot post a screen shot here lack of reputation so i am posting it here please see to it

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8651.png)

Comment: Please post a screenshot because I don't understand what you have and what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the Y axis maximum value to something that is higher than the biggest value.

Bar charts with value of zero must be displayed. If there isn't any value to be added than just use `MathHelper.NULL_VALUE`.

Comment: yes thats what i told you if i set the value to 60 the y axis shows me 20,40,60 values but i want it to show 10,20,30,40,50,60 in y axis

Comment: How to add MathHelper.NULL_VALUE and where do i to add?

Comment: Use renderer.setXLabels(10);

Comment: You add the NULL_VALUE in the place where you add 0, instead of 0.

Comment: i didnt get this can please explain You add the NULL_VALUE in the place where you add 0, instead of 0

Comment: and i tried renderer.setXLabels(10); but it still shows 20,40,60 in the Y axis

Comment: series.add(something, MathHelper.NULL_VALUE);

Comment: Dan  i need your help on this http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/ please help me

Comment: there are two things background color and margin color i need to add image to both how to do it?, i know that its not supported but i request you to please help me

Comment: Are you the one that opened issue #274?

Comment: yes yes its me, and if you can give me any hint on how to acheive that i will start on that

Comment: i have appiled background image to the bar chart now only one thing is left out, if you dont mind can you help me ?

Comment: Have you read this: "I don't have time right now. Maybe later in the week."?

Comment: However, I wonder how the margins would look like with a background image?

Comment: so sorry to disturb you,No i have added a background to layout and added the bar chart to that layout now it looks like it has a background to bar chart, but when i scroll to left the bars overlaps with Y axis values (10,20,30,40,50)i just to know how to hide it when we are scrolling to left? previously i had given WHITE as background color, this is only small change i require from you

Comment: I can see the x axis values 1,2,3,4,5 hides when scrolling to left

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700819/achart-enigne-bar-chart-hide-the-series-when-scrolling-to-right

Comment: Ok , but if i give margin color the graph looks very bad, is there any work around for that? the guy who has asked the question has also said the same thing

Comment: I think you are the same guy. You have exactly the same style as him.

Comment: Please let me know once your are free, and thanks a lot for everything  i will submit this demo for intern, but please help me solve that issue for main exams.

Comment: @user2056563 See my updated answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700819/achart-enigne-bar-chart-hide-the-series-when-scrolling-to-right

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

One of the ways is to set the margin color to transparent in the renderer

```
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));
```

This solution works unless your series have values that are outside the range of the chart. You can either recreate your series so all values are inside the range, or go for solution 2.

Solution 2 is to multiply the max Y value of your chart by 1.1, and set it as the Y max

```
mRenderer.setYAxisMax(maxvalue*1.1);
```